# Ultimo registro generado en la base de datos con una condicion

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Tengo una base de datos a la que llegan eventos de diferentes id, y me gustaría obtener el ultimo valor que ha llegado de cada id y que ese valor cumpla una condición.
Estoy probando esto, pero sólo me devuelve el último valor registrado en la base de datos.

```
 SELECT *
   FROM `tabla`
  WHERE Fechacompleta =
       (
        SELECT MAX(Fechacompleta)
         FROM `tabla`
        )
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar.
Gracias

---

Son dispositivos IoT con un ID cada uno, y estoy usando BigQuery de Google.
Gracias

Comment: Son muchos ID ? o definidos ID ?

Comment: Qué motor de base de datos estás usando? No lo dices por ninguna parte.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el último registro (el que tiene la fecha mayor) para cada `id`, lo que puedes hacer es numerar las filas (comenzando desde 1 para cada `id`) en orden descendente de acuerdo a la columna con la fecha, y luego filtrar aquellos registros cuyo número de fila es 1; eso te dará el último registro de cada `id`.

```
WITH sq AS (SELECT *,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Fechacompleta DESC) AS rn
            FROM tabla)

SELECT *
FROM sq
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Funcionó así @nachospiu graciassss

Comment: De nada @Javier88!!!

Answer (score 0):

Quizás este `query` solución a tu problema. Consiste un utilizar `LAST_INSERT_ID()` de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @tuTabla;
```

Importante que no olvides el `@` antes de añadir el nombre de la tabla a la que quieres consultar el último valor añadido.

Básicamente lo que haces con este query es seleccionar el último valor insertado el la tabla en la cual haces referencia en `INTO @TABLA`

Un saludo!

Comment: En caso de que tengas alguna duda o el código no te funcione debidamente escribe un comentario!!

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, Alexci. Una pregunta... Cómo tu respuesta ayuda a OP a resolver tu problema?

Comment: Perdona? No entiendo tu pregunta

Comment: Ciertamente, no fue escrita con claridad. Mi pregunta es: Cómo tu respuesta ayuda a OP a resolver **su** problema/pregunta. Es decir, **Qué hace** tu solución y **cómo resuelve** el problema planteado en la pregunta.

Comment: De verdad crees que la respuesta no es lo suficientemente clara????

Comment: Ya he actualizado mi respuesta, pero que creo yo que era extremadamente obvio lo que hace el query ``:~

Comment: Hola Alexci, el tema es que uso Bigquery y ese código no me vale, no sé si es necesario hacer un select anidado, intenté también con un LIMIT1, pero claro me coge el último evento registrado en la base de datos, no el último de cada id. Son dispositivos IoT que me están enviando info cada vez que ocurre algo.

Comment: Bueno, tal vez no era extremadamente obvio, eh?

Comment: Madre mía....hahahhaa